# Retrieve Firebase database specific value depending on key with angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

as the title says I build a CRUD application using Angular 5 and CRUD works just fine but now I need to retrieve a specific post data with advanced routing so the url should be something like : 
`https://example.com/blog/howtoDoSomething`
and the page should contain this post details like name, content , image and so on .

I tried

`details.component.ts`

```
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.key = params['$key']; 
});
```

`details.component.html`

```
<p>
 this page about {{ $key }}
</p>
```

the above code worked fine with angular 4 with some difference of course and I used a json file not Firebase .

---

I also tried this one :

`details.component.ts`

```
var x = this.blogService.getData();
        x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
        this.blogList = [];
        item.forEach(element => {
        var y = element.payload.toJSON();
        y["$key"] = element.key;
        this.blogList.push(y as Blog);
    });
});
```

`details.component.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let blog of blogList">
    {{blog[$key].title}}
</div>
```

this one if I use blog alone like :

```
<div *ngFor="let blog of blogList">
    {{blog}}
</div>
```

this retrieves the whole database as as 
`[object object]` repeated

thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you please provide what console.log(this.blogList) shows?

Comment: @Kraken `undefined` :\

Comment: So how it can show [object object]? Maybe you placed log to early?

Comment: @SaberHosney Could you clarify your post? I'm having a hard time understanding what your question is.

Comment: @EricLarson when I navigate to `https://example.com/user/userName` I should get this user details , clear enough ?

Comment: That doesn't tell me what your problem is. See my answer below.

Comment: @Kraken take a look http://i.epvpimg.com/WCjqdab.jpg

Comment: Put it inside subscription call back, and show me what is going on, we will fix it

Comment: @Kraken wired still undefined

Comment: This is impossible. it is undefined, and renders on you browser? Try to put it everywhere) i need to know what is inside of this

Comment: @Kraken I put it in service so it's almost everywhere that's the output http://i.epvpimg.com/iFGTaab.jpg , [Github repo](https://github.com/pro-devel/angular5-blog) if you want to see the full code

Answer (score 0):

```
// user-service.ts
public getUser(userId: string) {
    return this.afs.doc('users/' + userId).valueChanges();
)

// user-component.ts
// Get userId from route
this.user$ = this.userService.getUser(userId);

// user-component.html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
    {{user | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: I declared userId but it shows error userId isn't defined

Comment: `userId: string;` btw `afs` stands for ? I used it as AngularFireDatabase